# Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response when editing a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am trying to edit a book on my review app. Recently got AWS S3 to work with carrierwave. I've granted the user S3 Full Access and Administrator Access permmissions yet when I go to submit the edit form I get this error: Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response

I've done research on this error and usually it's because the permissions for the IAM user aren't granted...but in my case, they are. Maybe I didn't do it right?? AWS isn't exactly user friendly...